# Run a shell command on every line matching pattern

Tags: vim

I'd like to run `jq` on every line matching a specific pattern, I've tried with:

```
:g/^\s\+{/!jq .
```

where `^\s+{` is my pattern but it doesn't work. I get a lot of errors like this:

```
...

:!jq .
[No write since last change]

:!jq .
[No write since last change]

...
```

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

I can do for instance:

```
 g/^\s\+{/p
```

which will work and will print all of the lines matching my pattern

Comment: What specifically doesn't work? Is jq on your path? Does your regexp not match etc.?

Comment: I've edited the question. `jq` is in my path. I receive errors regarding invocation most likely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have a file with multiple JSON documents, each one concatenated on a single line, and you now want to pretty-print each such document into indented, multi-line ones with `jq .`

What you do with `:g/^\s\+{/` is locating lines with JSON documents, and then executing the command on it. The problem is in the `:!jq .` The way I've written it, you may already recognize that this is [`:help :!cmd`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%3A%21cmd), whereas you've intended to *filter* the current line (a JSON document spread over multiple subsequent lines would also work, but require a range). The filtering command is subtly different; [`:help :range!`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3Arange%21).

So, with `:!jq .`, Vim just launches the external `jq` with the `.` argument, but it doesn't pass anything from the buffer to it. That's why `jq` is just sitting there and waiting for input until you abort it (e.g. with `<C-c>`).

The `:.!jq .` command instead passes the current line `:.` as a *range* to the `jq` command, and then replaces the original line with the command's output, just as you want. Adding that single `.` fixes your command:

```
:g/^\s\+{/.!jq .
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was missing